# can I use google analytics during development of website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics

I am developing a RubyonRails website which is product based. I need to show number of views of product.So I prefer google analytics.

But google analytics expects valid domain name.How can I use google analytics in development mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics needs a valid domain when setting up the profile, but you can use the same basic tracking code both on your production and development site.

If you needed to track sessions between the two domains it gets more complicated, but it doesn't sound like you need to worry about that.

Comment: I have verified google analytics reports as soon as I added tracking code.But google updated the report after 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to mind would be to have a page in a live site with the analytics js, then load that page in an invisible iframe in your development site. The URL you'd load in the iframe could have parameters so analytics can identify the page uniquely.